# How to Send GPS Data to Firebase via SIM808 GSM Module

Tags: gsm, gps, sim808

I have an Arduino UNO with SIM808 and I'm trying to send my GPS data to the Firebase. I have successfully get a location from SIM808 via serial. However I found that Arduino only supported HTTP communication while the Firebase accepted only HTTPS requests. How can I connect them (Arduino and Firebase) so I can send data to Firebase. Any guide and help can help me a lot thank you so much :)

Comment: don't use an Arduino UNO for the project